# Importing class in the same package

Tags: java

I went through some of topics, but didn't find a proper anser. I'm trying to import class to other class, but I get *"The import "classname" cannot be resolved"* error. Both classes are in the same package. What can cause the problem? I also tried to clean my project.

Comment: You do not need to `import` classes from the same package.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If both classes are in same package, you don't have to import it.

Comment: Some methods still won't work without this, why is that? Sorry if im asking an obvious questions but im very new im codeing, and trying to learn as much as possible.

Comment: They probably are private. Private methods are only available from the class they are inside of.

Comment: "Some methods..." please show the code. Maybe even post a new question, since the new information may make the given answer invalid.